# How to fix Unity Error CS0103 in a 2D Platformer game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Currently working on a 2D Platformer for a college class, and have run into Unity Error CS0103. I know what the error means, I just don't know why my code doesn't work.

Error is on Line 43, at the "playerDead = true;"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spawnLocation;
    Rigidbody2D rigidLink;
    CapsuleCollider2D capsuleLink;
    Animator animatorLink;
    [SerializeField] PlayerController controllerLink;
    AudioSource audioLink;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip playerDiesClip;
    PlayerController playerLink;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidLink.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        capsuleLink.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();
        animatorLink.GetComponent<Animator>();
        audioLink.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    private IEnumerator TimeDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        transform.position = spawnLocation.transform.position;
        controllerLink.enabled = true;
        capsuleLink.enabled = true;
        rigidLink.gravityScale = 1;
        animatorLink.Play("Idle");
    }

    void PlayerDies()
    {
        controllerLink.enabled = false;
        capsuleLink.enabled = false;
        rigidLink.gravityScale = 0;
        rigidLink.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        animatorLink.Play("Die");
        audioLink.PlayOneShot(playerDiesClip);
        StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
        playerDead = true;
    }


    private void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
    {
        var hitTag = collision.collider.gameObject.tag;

        if (hitTag == "EnemyMelee")
        {
            PlayerDies();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with this. I'm following the instructions from the professor and I keep running into errors.

Comment: Well, CS0103 - *The name 'identifier' does not exist in the current context*

Comment: There is no variable called `playerDead`. What is it that you're trying to set?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi ToasterOvenIII (nice name),

playerDead is a variable that you want to make, but you haven't declared it anywhere, nor have you given it a type if you want to declare it here. Don't worry, a lot of early coders make this mistake, especially when switching from a type-infered language like python or javascript.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I did NOT see that, and that gave me enough momentum to figure out what was wrong with other bits of my code! I implemented it and everything works fine! Thanks for helping out.